# Getting invalid json file by python for loop

Tags: python, json, screen-scraping

hello first of all i'm trying to do a web scraper bot and then save all info in a json file
but when looping my json is invalid

this is part of my code and where i'm generating json

```
for tag in tags:
             myarr=tag.getText(strip=True)
             words=myarr.split()
             titles = []
             titles.append(words)
             data = [{"data": w} for w in zip(titles)]



             with open('data.json', 'a+',encoding='utf-8') as f:  

              json.dump(data, f,indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

and this is part of my invalid json file that was been generated by python

```
[
  {
    "data": [
      [
        "Acuña",
        "Game",
        "GermánEspecialidad:Tratamiento",
        "del",
        "DolorLugar",
        "de",
        "Atención:Centro",
        "de",
        "Diagnóstico",
        "1"
      ]
    ]
  }
][
  {
    "data": [
      [
        "Aguayo",
        "Baeza",
        "EdgardoEspecialidad:Reumatología",
        "AdultosLugar",
        "de",
        "Atención:Centro",
        "de",
        "Diagnóstico",
        "1",
        "Piso",
        "7"
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

while trying to parse this json on a online json parser it says SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ in JSON at position 318

is there anyway to generate a valid json?
if yes anyone that can help  me out?

Comment: your json is just missing an outside `{` `}` to enclose everything and a `,` between each data. You can make the adjustment in your loop

Comment: First generate your data, then json.dump() everything at once.

Comment: @MikeTung i added , with `f.write(",")` but still giving me a syntax error on online parser also i tried to add `{` `}` but no luck i'm really new to python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's json module doesn't directly support building a json file incrementally<sup>*</sup>.  Valid json can be generated by appending each each dict to a list, and then dumping the list to the output file, like this:

```
data = []
for tag in tags:
     myarr=tag.getText(strip=True)
     words=myarr.split()
     titles = []
     titles.append(words)
     data.extend({"data": w} for w in zip(titles))

# Once all the data has been processed, write to file.  
with open('data.json', 'w',encoding='utf-8') as f:  
    json.dump(data, f,indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

<sup>*</sup> From the docs for [json.dump](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump):

> ...trying to serialize multiple objects with repeated calls to dump() using the same fp will result in an invalid JSON file

Comment: hello thanks for your answer i tried the code but i'm getting the folowing error
https://pastebin.com/KbXZXXCx

Comment: I suspect that you want to change `data.append` to `data.extend` in the code (I've changed this in the answer).  `({"data": w} for w in zip(titles))
` is a generator expression, and the json module doesn't know how to handle it.  However by using `list.extend` method you can expand the generator into a list, and json will do the right thing.